# getting started with rspec in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, testing, rspec

I'm trying to write a spec for a Student class. So far it's simple; it only has a first name and a last name. I need to make sure both those fields aren't blank. I have this so far:

```
describe Student do
    context "is valid" do
            before do
              @student = Student.new
            end

            it "should have a first name" do
              expect(student).not_to be_valid
            end

            it "should have a last name" do
              expect(student).not_to be_valid
            end
        end
    end
```

When I run the tests it says student is an undefined local variable for both of them. Why does the before not work?

Comment: Replace `student` with `@student`.

Answer (score 0):

Because `@student` is an instance variable, and RSpec does not create attributes automagically. If you want to use `student` instead of `@student`, use `let`:

```
describe Student do
  context "is valid" do
    let(:student) { Student.new }

    it "should have a first name" do
      expect(student).not_to be_valid
    end

    it "should have a last name" do
      expect(student).not_to be_valid
    end
  end 
end
```

Related documentation: http://www.betterspecs.org/#let